# Calculation of the total energy of a spaceplane

Tags: spacecraft, energy

I am trying to calculate the total energy change of a spaceplane during its flight time. From the data I have and the calculations I made, I created an excel table in which I included:

- flight time : from 0 s to 147 s ( with a step of 5s)
- Height at time t -->h(t)
- Speed at time t and h(t)-->V(h)

Knowing the dry mass (Md), propellant mass (Mp) and  propellant flow rate(*m*), I calculated the mass at time t as follows:

**m(t) = Md + (Mp- *m* * t)**

Considering that after 57 seconds the engine shuts down, the mass remains unchanged from this point on.

So the total energy is:

**E = 1/2 * m(t) * V^2 + m(t)* g* h(t)**

Keeping in mind that about 120 s the spaceplane begins its descent; Energy should increase until 120s and then begin to decrease.

Instead, I get that after 120 s the energy increases, and I cannot explain why.
Can you help me ?

Edit: This is the spreadsheet

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your work! Edit your question and include, say, 10 of the lines from your spreadsheet. Use good judgement in picking which 10.

Comment: Additional information: this work concerns the flight profile of the SpaceshipTwo

Comment: in strictly mathematical terms, the height barely changes after 120s but the velocity goes up dramatically (from 0 to more than a thousand meters per second).  Are you sure you have good data?

Comment: Yes, I know that the data available to me is not very accurate. i will try to find something more accurate. But anyway being that the spacecraft starts its descent it is normal that the speed increases. 0 is in the apogee and than start the non powered descent.

Comment: tl;dr based on Erin Anne's comment and Gabriel Sanchez's answer: Your results are bad because the data is bad. Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Erin Anne mentioned, is not that the data is "not accurate", is that there is something very wrong with the data after apogee.

Assuming v=0 at t=120s, and acceleration equals to roughly -9.8 m/s^2 given that the vehicle is now in free fall (lets neglect any drag given the height). After 27 seconds at t=147s the maximum velocity should be around 265 m/s (a*t). To reach 1041 m/s in 27 seconds as the data suggest (dV/dt), the plane should accelerate at roughly 38.6 m/s^2 or roughly 4g.

Unless the plane was somehow boosted at 3g on descent, your data looks weird because your kinetic energy after apogee is around 15 times what it should be. (I haven't checked if the data before apogee actually makes sense, but you probably should)